# why didn't get correct percentage ratio in pie chart with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am frustrated about percentage ratio in pie chart. I don't why but the percentage was wrong in the pie chart. I think plotting function misunderstood the plotting data then gave me the wrong percentage value in the pie chart. what was the problem? how to fix this? any idea?

**my attempt and minimal data**

here is [minimal data on the public gist](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/16cb632934a2293f2513e39a90732e7e).

**my attempt**:

```
 import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('piechart.csv', encoding='utf-8')
labels = tuple(df.index)
total_sum = df['qty1_sum'].sum()
sizes=[58, 50, 66, 53, 48, 48, 34, 49, 59, 48]

fig1, ax1 =plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
pie = ax1.pie(sizes, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.8),  autopct= '%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90, textprops={'fontsize': 12})
tot_sum=str(total_sum) + '\n Metric Tons'
ax1.text(0., 0., tot_sum, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set(title="top 10 country by export")
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax1.legend(pie[0],top10_cty, loc="upper right", fontsize=20, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1.25))
plt.show()
```

when I run my code, percent of each country was wrong, for example, Japan should have 29% but in my attempted code, it gave me 11% value. why? how to fix this problem? where is the source of this issue? any quick solution? thanks

**why I insist that percentage wrong**

I manually calculated the percentage for each country and in pie chart percentage value was wrong. I don't know why. any idea to track down the source of the issue? thanks

Comment: "Japan should have 29%". It's hard to verify/correct this as there is no reference to "Japan" in your code, and you haven't included the `piechart.csv` file.

Comment: You are reading a file `piechart.csv` from your computer's local file system. How should anyone know what the contents are and use it to assess your program?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco oops I forgot the link for the [gist data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/16cb632934a2293f2513e39a90732e7e). you could see it now and what's going on on with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japan should have 29.97 %, which is rounded to one decimal as 30.0 %.

The principal problem is that the code uses a fixed list `sizes=[58, 50, ...]` instead of using the values from the dataframe.

Filling in the correct columns to use for the pie chart and for the labels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('piechart.csv', encoding='utf-8')
total_sum = df['qty1_sum'].sum()

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
pie = ax1.pie(df['qty1_sum'], wedgeprops=dict(width=0.8), autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
              textprops={'fontsize': 12})
tot_sum = str(round(total_sum)) + '\nMetric Tons'
ax1.text(0., 0., tot_sum, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set(title="top 10 country by export")
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax1.legend(pie[0], df['cty_ptn'], loc="upper right", fontsize=20, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1.25))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]